# Pushing an object to an array - react native & Firestore

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a brainfart that lasts embarrassingly too long and would appreciate your help -
I keep getting the following error when trying to push an object to my array:

```
TypeError: cannot add a new property, js engine: hermes
```

This is my function:

```
export const fetchRecipesOfUser = async (collectionPath: string): Promise<Recipe[]> => {
  try {
    let items: Recipe[] = [];

    const ref = firestore().collection(collectionPath);
    await ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let r: Recipe = {
          id: doc.id,
          name: doc.data().name,
          image: doc.data().image,
          duration: doc.data().duration,
          serving: doc.data().serving,
          category: doc.data().category,
          ingredients: doc.data().ingredients,
          preparationSteps: doc.data().preparationSteps,
        };
        // console.log(r); // <- the object is as should be
        items.push(r); // gives me the error
      });
    });
    return items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  }
};
```

What am I missing here?

Even when I tried to:

```
items[items.length] = r;
return items;
```

I got back an empty array